# How to return nothing if there are no matches?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, shortcode

```
add_shortcode( 'subscribe-to-category', function() {
   global $wpdb, $post;
 
$the_cat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
$category_name = $the_cat[0]->cat_name;
   $id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM wptq_forms WHERE name = '{$category_name}';"));
   return do_shortcode( '[newsletter_form id="' . intval( $id ) . '"]' );
} );
```

I am matching the name of the first category of the current post with form titles to append the correct form id into a form shortcode that is in my post template.

How do I write the code so, that if there are no matches, no shortcode will be displayed at all?

The issue is that currently if there are no matches, then id 0 will be assigned to the shortcode automatically.

But once I've put [subscribe-to-category] in my template, it seems impossible to totally remove the shortcode if there are no matches...

The issue is multiple categories. I have max 2-3 categories per post.
I want to show a separate subscribe form (button + mail field) for each category of the current post.
(That will notify by e-mail if new posts are posted in that category.)
So I will have to insert the code above 3 times, once checking for the first, then for the second, and then for the third category, and give them different shortcode names.

If there is no second or third category, then those shortcodes should not be displayed.

Is there any smarter way to achieve what I want?

Comment: (Possible) side note: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries. The [`wpdb::prepare()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) supports parameters, use them!

Comment: Ah, I added the $wpdb->prepare parenthesis and I tought I am done with SQL injection protection. So thanks, I'll have to research your suggestion further and see how to implement it in the code. Eventually I would be greatful for an example code...

Comment: Does `$id` come back as null when nothing is found? If so `if (is_null($id)) { return ''; }` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @Greg Schmidt, it did the trick, it does work.